# My table isn't showing correctly

Tags: tables, math-mode, tabularx

Here's my code -

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.7cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,right=5cm,marginparwidth=3.5cm,marginparsep=1cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
         \centering
          \begin{tabular}[c|c|c|c]
                  \toprule
                  $p$ & $q$ & $p \rightarrow q$ & $q$ \\
                  \midrule
                  T & T & T & T \\
                  T & F & F & F \\
                  F & T & T & T \\
                  F & F & T & F \\
                  \bottomrule
          \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should (1) provide an image of what it looks like at your en, (2) explian what is wrong, (3) explain what you expected to see.

Comment: (4) Let me guess: are you using OverLeaf? Your example does not compile as the `[H]` specifier is not defined by default, and in general should not be used.

Comment: (5) The rules from `booktabs` does not work with vertical lines (by design). In general don't use vertical lines, it just makes the same harder to read.

Comment: (6) it is `\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}` (curly braces, not square)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors

1. the `[H]` placement is not defined by default. Use `[htbp]`
2. Use `\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}` not `\begin{tabular}[c|c|c|c]`

Comment: `booktabs` roles looks really bad (by design) with vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `tabular` is *mandatory*, so braces, not (square brackets).

Vertical rules make for hard reading, better to omit them.

You never want `[H]` nor need `table` unless you want to caption the table. A simple math display does the job.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.7cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,right=5cm,marginparwidth=3.5cm,marginparsep=1cm}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{cccc}   
\toprule
$p$ & $q$ & $p \rightarrow q$ & $q$ \\
\midrule
T & T & T & T \\
T & F & F & F \\
F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & F \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The case, where vertical lines works well with rules of `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[hmargin={2.7cm,5cm}, vmargin=4cm,
            marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=1cm
            ]{geometry}
            
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{vline{2-Y}={solid},
             cells=c,
             row{1} = {mode=math}
             }
    \toprule
p   & q & p \rightarrow q   & q \\
    \midrule
  T & T & T & T \\
  T & F & F & F \\
  F & T & T & T \\
  F & F & T & F \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But without vertical lines is nicer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[hmargin={2.7cm,5cm}, vmargin=4cm,
            marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=1cm
            ]{geometry}
            
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{cells=c,
             row{1} = {mode=math}
             }
    \toprule
p   & q & p \rightarrow q   & q \\
    \midrule
  T & T & T & T \\
  T & F & F & F \\
  F & T & T & T \\
  F & F & T & F \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]